# C# Algorithmic Game Theory API

Tags: c#, game-theory

I recently came accross Gambit - http://www.gambit-project.org/doc/index.html - a C++ algorithmic game theory API.

Is anyone aware of a .NET Game Theory Library?

Answer (score 2):

I know this would take a small bit of time, but you could download the source for the C++ project you cited and compile it into a DLL that you could reference in your C# project. [This link](http://blogs.artinsoft.net/mrojas/archive/2008/12/19/use-c-in-c.aspx) contains information about doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any existing library.

The minimax algorithm is pretty easy to implement if you are doing a 2 player game. The following pseudocode is plagiarised from the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax#Pseudocode):

```
function integer minimax(node, depth)
    if node is a terminal node or depth <= 0:
        return the heuristic value of node
    α = -∞
    for child in node:   # evaluation is identical for both players 
        α = max(α, -minimax(child, depth-1))
    return α
```

If you are doing more than 2 players, then there is Sturtevant and Korf's [MaxN algorithm](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.83.1244&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

I've implemented these before, and they are pretty easy. It should be very straightforward in .Net.

Comment: sure these algorithms are straightforward, but does anyone know a framework that encapsulates some of the aspects of Game Theory: payoff tables, nash equilibriums, game types, competioition vs cooperation, reciprocity, utility, insurance, domination, randomization, perfect / imperfect info, subgame perfection, evolutionary dynamics, conventions, repeated games etc ?